# Reliable way to determine file size on POSIX/OS X given a file descriptor

Tags: macos, caching, posix, bsd, kqueue

I wrote a function to watch a file (given an fd) growing to a certain size including a timeout. I'm using `kqueue()`/`kevent()` to wait for the file to be "extended" but after I get the notification that the file grew I have to check the file size (and compare it against the desired size). That seems to be easy but I cannot figure out a way to do that reliably in POSIX.

NB: The timeout will hit if the file doesn't grow at all for the time specified. So, this is not an absolute timeout, just a timeout that some growing happens to the file. I'm on OS X but this question is meant for "every POSIX that has `kevent()`/`kqueue()`", that should be OS X and the BSDs I think.

Here's my current version of my function:

```
/**
 * Blocks until `fd` reaches `size`. Times out if `fd` isn't extended for `timeout`
 * amount of time. Returns `-1` and sets `errno` to `EFBIG` should the file be bigger
 * than wanted.
 */
int fwait_file_size(int fd,
                    off_t size,
                    const struct timespec *restrict timeout)
{
    int ret = -1;
    int kq = kqueue();
    struct kevent changelist[1];

    if (kq < 0) {
        /* errno set by kqueue */
        ret = -1;
        goto out;
    }

    memset(changelist, 0, sizeof(changelist));
    EV_SET(&changelist[0], fd, EVFILT_VNODE, EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE | EV_CLEAR, NOTE_DELETE | NOTE_RENAME | NOTE_EXTEND, 0, 0);

    if (kevent(kq, changelist, 1, NULL, 0, NULL) < 0) {
        /* errno set by kevent */
        ret = -1;
        goto out;
    }

    while (true) {
        {
            /* Step 1: Check the size */
            int suc_sz = evaluate_fd_size(fd, size); /* IMPLEMENTATION OF THIS IS THE QUESTION */
            if (suc_sz > 0) {
                /* wanted size */
                ret = 0;
                goto out;
            } else if (suc_sz < 0) {
                /* errno and return code already set */
                ret = -1;
                goto out;
            }
        }

        {
            /* Step 2: Wait for growth */
            int suc_kev = kevent(kq, NULL, 0, changelist, 1, timeout);

            if (0 == suc_kev) {
                /* That's a timeout */
                errno = ETIMEDOUT;
                ret = -1;
                goto out;
            } else if (suc_kev > 0) {
                if (changelist[0].filter == EVFILT_VNODE) {
                    if (changelist[0].fflags & NOTE_RENAME || changelist[0].fflags & NOTE_DELETE) {
                        /* file was deleted, renamed, ... */
                        errno = ENOENT;
                        ret = -1;
                        goto out;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                /* errno set by kevent */
                ret = -1;
                goto out;
            }
        }
    }

    out: {
        int errno_save = errno;
        if (kq >= 0) {
            close(kq);
        }
        errno = errno_save;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

So the basic algorithm works the following way:

1. Set up the kevent
2. Check size
3. Wait for file growth

Steps 2 and 3 are repeated until the file reached the wanted size.

The code uses a function `int evaluate_fd_size(int fd, off_t wanted_size)` which will return `< 0` for "some error happened or file larger than wanted", `== 0` for "file not big enough yet", or `> 0` for file has reached the wanted size.

Obviously this only works if `evaluate_fd_size` is reliable in determining file size. My first go was to implement it with `off_t eof_pos = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` and compare `eof_pos` against `wanted_size`. Unfortunately, `lseek` seems to cache the results. So even when `kevent` returned with `NOTE_EXTEND`, so the file grew, the result may be the same! Then I thought to switch to `fstat` but [found articles that `fstat` caches as well](http://blog.charlescary.com/?p=4).

The last thing I tried was using `fsync(fd);` before `off_t eof_pos = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);` and suddenly things started working. But:

1. Nothing states that `fsync()` really solves my problem
2. I don't want to `fsync()` because of performance

**EDIT**: It's really hard to reproduce but I saw one case in which `fsync()` didn't help. It seems to take (very little) time until the file size is larger after a `NOTE_EXTEND` event hit user space. `fsync()` probably just works as a good enough `sleep()` and therefore it works most of the time :-.

So, in other words: How to reliably check file size in POSIX without opening/closing the file which I cannot do because I don't know the file name. Additionally, I can't find a guarantee that this would help

By the way: `int new_fd = dup(fd); off_t eof_pos = lseek(new_fd, 0, SEEK_END); close(new_fd);` did not overcome the caching issue.

**EDIT 2**: I also created an [all in one demo program](https://gist.github.com/weissi/7890467#file-file-size-c). If it prints `Ok, success` before exiting, everything went fine. But usually it prints `Timeout (10000000)` which manifests the race condition: The file size check for the last kevent triggered is smaller than the actual file size at this very moment. Weirdly when using `ftruncate()` to grow the file instead of `write()` it seems to work (you can compile the test program with `-DUSE_FTRUNCATE` to test that).

Comment: Can you try doing a `fchown(fd, -1, -1)` before calling stat ?

Comment: @cnicutar Tried that, didn't help :-(

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Nothing states that fsync() really solves my problem
> 2. I don't want to fsync() because of performance

Your problem isn't "fstat caching results", it's the I/O system buffering writes. Fstat doesn't get updated until the kernel flushes the I/O buffers to the underlying file system.

This is why fsync fixes your problem and any solution to your problem more or less has to do the equivalent of fsync. ( This is what the open/close solution does as a side effect. )

Can't help you with 2 because I don't see any way to avoid doing fsync.

Comment: Edited my question, `fsync()` apparently does not solve the problem entirely. I've see one case where it wasn't enough. I guess it just pauses the program execution for some time and therefore reduces the number of cases where I can observe the race condition.